# Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this error:

```
Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type '{ id: string; name: string; persnr: string; }': id, name, persnr" 

        28 |
        29 |     return (
      > 30 |         <ChatContext.Provider value={[chatPartner, dispatch]}>
           |                               ^
        31 |             {props.children}
        32 |         </ChatContext.Provider>
        33 |     );
```

but I do not understand it. What is wrong here?

```
import React, {useReducer, createContext} from "react";

const initialState = {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    persnr: '',
};

export const ChatContext = createContext(initialState);

const reducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SELECTED_CHAT":
            return (action.payload);
        case "RESET_SELECTED_CHAT":
            return {
                id: '',
                name: '',
                persnr: '',
            };
        default:
            return initialState
    }
};

export const ChatContextProvider = (props: any) => {
    const [chatPartner, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return (
        <ChatContext.Provider value={[chatPartner, dispatch]}>
            {props.children}
        </ChatContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Either: `[chatPartner, dispatch]` is a valid value of the context, in which case `initialState` is not a valid default, or vice versa. You might want to start by _explicitly supplying the generic_ when creating the context, so the compiler can tell you _which_ is wrong - we can't.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed to `<ChatContext.Provider/>` component  is `[chatPartner, dispatch]`, so the TS type of the context is:

```
[State, Dispatch<ReducerAction<typeof reducer>>]
```

See below full code:

```
import React, {
  useReducer,
  createContext,
  Dispatch,
  ReducerAction,
} from 'react';

const initialState = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  persnr: '',
};

type State = typeof initialState;

type PayloadAction<P = void, T extends string = string> = {
  payload: P;
  type: T;
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: PayloadAction<State>) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SELECTED_CHAT':
      return action.payload;
    case 'RESET_SELECTED_CHAT':
      return {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        persnr: '',
      };
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};

export const ChatContext = createContext<
  [State, Dispatch<ReducerAction<typeof reducer>>]
>([initialState, () => {}]);

export const ChatContextProvider = (props: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [chatPartner, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <ChatContext.Provider value={[chatPartner, dispatch]}>
      {props.children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-scfuai?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

package version:

```json
react: 18.2.0
```